# Keyboard shortcuts (spacebar) no longer works in Photos on Mojave

Tags: photos, photos.app

Until recently, pressing spacebar toggled expanding my photos in Photos, and single keys provided a way to edit photos (e.g. C for crop). None of these features now work for me.

How do I restore keyboard shortcuts in Photos?

Comment: What exactly happened between "until recently" and "now"? Any upgrades, updates, software installs etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in macOS 10.14.4 (Photo 4.0): spacebar now opens images and keyboard shortcuts work for editing.

Answer (score 3):

Since MacOS Mojave, Photos have changed shortcuts. I used Space key very extensively, so made work again ([link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mojave-photos-app.2122059/page-2)):

- Go to preferences > keyboard > shortcuts > app shortcuts > Photos > and add a shortcut.
- For Menu Title enter "Open Viewer" and for the keyboard shortcut press the spacebar whilst holding the Fn key.
- Add another one for "Close Viewer"
- Add another one for "Open/Close Viewer"
- Now open Photos, go to Library/Photos, select single photo and click on menu "Image" - check if Open Viewer shows "Space"
- Press Spacebar and enjoy :)

Also few useful shortcuts:

- cmd+Enter - edit mode
- cmd+1 - in edit mode Adjust
- cmd+3 - in edit mode Crop
- . - make photo favorite

Also check cmd+1-4 and ctrl+1-6 in photos view mode :)

And desert: [All Photos keyboard shortcuts for Mojave](https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/keyboard-shortcuts-pht6e593112/4.0/mac/10.14)