# Mojave Photos - Space Bar to Preview fix not working

Tags: macos, photos, mojave, photos.app

In macOS Mojave, tapping the space bar to open a picture in Viewer does not work.  I have tried the  fix in this thread: [Keyboard shortcuts (spacebar) no longer works in Photos on Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338126/keyboard-shortcuts-spacebar-no-longer-works-in-photos-on-mojave)

However it only works to open, not close.  I can not comment or post on that thread so I'm forced to open a new one.

Has anyone found a fix that gets close to work using the Space key?

Answer (score 1):

As of Mojave 10.14.4 - Photos has changed back to the normal use of the space bar to preview an image. So if your have not upgraded yet, do that :)